# Confused between proxy and reverse proxy

Tags: proxies

I need one line explanation for proxy and reverse proxy. When I post any project on freelancer they ask whether I want a backconnect rotating proxy / reverse proxy etc.

Anyone?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A pair of simple definitions would be:

Forward Proxy: Acting on behalf of a requestor (or service consumer)

Reverse Proxy: Acting on behalf of service/content producer.

Answer (score 2):

Proxy: It is making the request on behalf of the client. So, the server will return the response to the proxy, and the proxy will forward the response to the client. In fact, the server will never "learn" who the client was (the client's IP address); it will only know the proxy. However, the client definitely knows the server, since it essentially formats the HTTP request destined for the server, but it just hands it to the proxy.

Reverse Proxy: It is receiving the request on behalf of the server. It forwards the request to the server, receives the response and then returns the response to the client. In this case, the client will never "learn" who was the actual server (the server's IP address) (with some exceptions); it will only know the proxy. The server will or won't know the actual client, depending on the configurations of the reverse proxy.